# jQuery UI draggable only to left

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, pixel

How can I drag an element only to the left and only for X pixels?

Obviously using jQuery UI Draggable.

I've tried something like

```
$('li').draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    containment: [0,0,-250,250]
});
```

But it doesn't do what I want..

EDIT: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MJvn8/

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Yes, http://jsfiddle.net/MJvn8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with something like:

```
var startPosition = 0;
$('li').draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        startPosition = ui.position.left;
    },
    drag: function( event, ui ) {
        if(ui.position.left > startPosition)
            ui.position.left = startPosition;
        if(ui.position.left < -250)
            ui.position.left = -250;
        startPosition = ui.position.left;
    }
});
```

**[Check This Example](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/MJvn8/15/)**

**Update**

To allow a user to get back to the original position **[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/MJvn8/16/)**

Comment: @DavideR please mark this answer as accepted if it resolved your question or give feedback.  Thanks

Comment: Yeah it works, but how can I also drag it back to the original position?